# Parent font-size is being effected by child's font-size

Tags: html, css

I have some very simple code which is:

```
<p>
  <h3>Title is here</h3>
  This is the paragraph
</p>
```

CSS:

```
h2 {font-size:2.3em;}
h3 {font-size:1em;}
p {font-size:0.5em;}
```

Despite my font-size being set to different numbers in the CSS, the `<p>` always ends up using the `<h3>` font-size.  I know you're probably saying, just put the `<h3>` tag on the outside!  But I can't.  Not allowed in this case.  What's going on?

Comment: Show the css, are you using `em` instead of `px`?

Comment: What's going on is em inherits font size, you should use rem if you don't want to worry about child elements inheriting font sizes.

Comment: "Not allowed in this case."  It's funny you say that, because the HTML validator says that h3s are *not allowed* to be descendants of paragraphs.  Expect unexpected results when you write invalid markup.

Comment: Assuming the page is served as text/html (as usually), the only invalid part of this markup is the last </p> ("end tag for element "P" which is not open"). The end tag for P element is optional in HTML, and, since its content model allows only inline ("phrasing" in HTML5 terms) content, it is closed implicitely right before any block tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By defining the `font-size` with `px` and adding `!important` to the end, everything was fixed.

Comment: I would stray way from using `!important` declarations in your CSS.  They should be used as an **absolute last resort**.  But seeing as you have improper markup to begin with, I can see how you arrived at this conclusion.  I was under the impression you wanted to keep using `em` and not `px`.  I guess I should have included that in my answer.

Comment: Obviously it's not ideal, but neither is the code I was given to work with.  I wanted a solution to my particular problem, not an answer to how the code should look.

Answer (score 4):

Placing the h3 within the paragraph tag isn't the correct way to format your markup. I would recommend moving it out of the paragraph.

Comment: The browser will take it out of the paragraph tag for you. If you inspect the element in Chrome, you'll see that.

Comment: I said I can't take the `<h3>` tag out of the `<p>` tag.  I'm adjusting a very large project and it would not give off a uniform style at that point.

Comment: @kalley you shouldn't plan your markup based on that fact.  Based on your comment we all should forget about closing tags because the browser will add them for us?  Wrong.

Comment: You shouldn't use an H3 then, use a span, strong, or em tag. Maybe even add a class, but mark it up that way.

Comment: I don't know why this keeps getting upvoted.  It's the simple answer, not the correct one.  If I could move the `<h3>` tag then why even bother trying to find help.

Comment: @hungerstar that was not what I was saying. I was agreeing with the answer. Do not plan for that at all. Please. It was meant as more of a learning tool to see what actually happens and follow that example.

Comment: Why not do a find and replace as @KruegerDesigns suggests?  Then you don't have to worry about the browser messing with the markup.

Answer (score 2):

Even though you shouldn't be using that markup (as everyone here will agree).  I will give you a solution.

Let's say your base font size is `12px`.  Since the browser attempts to correct this improper markup by removing the `h3` from the `p`, your `p { font-size: 0.5em; }` does not get applied as it is no longer inside a `p`.  The text size does not end up being `6px` as you were expecting.  The `h3` is now inheriting the `12px` base font size in my example.  `1em` does not increase or reduce the size of the text.  Why? `1em x 12px = 12px`.

This is what the browser is doing:

```html
<p></p>
<h3>Title is here</h3>
This is the paragraph
<p></p>
```

So whatever the containing element is and whatever that's font-size is, will dictate the font-size of the string of text `This is the paragraph`.

So the simple answer is: increase the `em` value for your `h3`.  At some point you still might end up with unexpected results as other CSS might affect the base font size due to the improper markup and the browser's actions.

Comment: A caveat to this answer: Although this WILL allow you to get the text in your h3 element larger than the text in the p element, because everything is being removed from the p element by the browser no styles will be applied to the other text. If the author is going to go with a hacky solution like this, you might as well just nest another p element:

        <p>
  <h3>Title is here</h3>
  <p>This is the paragraph</p>
 </p>

Once the browser removes the contents of the outer p element, you are left with what the author wants...

Comment: I would think that if he has the ability to add markup as you suggest then he should be able to swap out a different tag as @KruegerDesigns suggests above.

Comment: A good point. If he cannot touch the markup at all, and can only modify the css, then yes I agree you have the only solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the problem:

[image]

As demonstrated by my gratuitous freehand circle, the `<h3>` isn't being read as a child of `<p>` and the text that should be in the `<p></p>` isn't, it is being placed in the body directly hence the css style for `<p>` isn't being applied to it.

You'll have to change your mark-up.

**If you really can't change your html you could do this:**

[Technically Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/Jecug/)

```
h2 {font-size:4.6em;}
h3 {font-size:2em;}
body{font-size:0.5em;}
```

## I really don't recommend it though...

Answer (score 0):

Look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/peW3p/ I have it outputting the generated HTML from the body. You can see what is happening. Everything in the `<p>` gets pulled out of it. This is what you're problem is. As suggested by @KruegerDesigns [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17436136/parent-font-size-is-being-effected-by-childs-font-size/17436167?noredirect=1#comment25328234_17436167), if you want to be able to know with any kind of certainty what your CSS is going to do, use something other than an `<h3>`.